# Temporarily disable AWS auto-scaling group activities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a way to temporarily disable an existing AWS auto-scaling group without deleting/recreating the group, or its triggers.
"Disabling" meaning: prevent any instance creation or deletion for a short period of time without wiping the whole related configuration.

Our current release process creates and configure new EC2 instance and inject them in our ELB once ready. It also remove old instances and stop them. For a very short time, the ELB contains twice the usual amount of EC2 instances.

This amount may exceed MAX instance count in the ELB for a very short duration. During this process, we'd like to prevent the auto-scaling group from terminating random supernumerary instances.

I could not find any « disable » option in amazon console. 
It may not match auto-scaling group philosophy. Did I missed something ?
Is there a tool for that through amazon command line tools or boto framework ?

Comment: When you say disable, do you mean to terminate all running instances related to the group, or only to stop all scaling activities?

Comment: Thanks, I reworded my question.
« prevent any instance creation or deletion for a short period of time without wiping the whole related configuration. »

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the autoscaling lingo, what you are asking about is [suspending processes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SuspendResume.html). In a nutshell each of the autoscaling activities (launch, terminate etc.) can be disabled for as long as you want.

It doesn't look you can set this from the web console (although it does display what processes are available), so you'll either have to use the [api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_SuspendProcesses.html) or the command line tools

From the [cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/suspend-processes.html) that's just

```
aws autoscaling suspend-processes --auto-scaling-group-name MyGroup
```

and later on

```
aws autoscaling resume-processes --auto-scaling-group-name MyGroup
```

You can pass specific processes to suspend resume as extra arguments, but you probably don't need to do that.

Comment: Not sure how it was back in '14 but it seems to be available and modifiable from the AWS console now (under the Details tab, in edit mode)

Answer (score 4):

Not the best way to do things, but works if you do not have CLI access at the moment.

to use the web console to remove all instances from an aws scaling  group: Set  max. instances, min. instances, and desired instances to 0;

Answer (score 3):

You can make the MAX instance = 3 and MIN instance = 3 i.e. Specifying the same instance count for both min and max.

This way there shouldn't be any change in the instance count no matter what your rules are.

Answer (score 2):

Set your Desired Capacity Min and Max to 0. Save. Check on Activity History and you'll see the instances being terminated.

Answer (score 1):

From horse's mouth...thanks to wonderful aws documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html)
I'm coping all the steps here just in case if the url changes:

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/,
   and choose **Auto Scaling Groups** from the navigation pane.
2. Select the check box next to the **Auto Scaling group**.

   A split pane opens up in the bottom of the Auto Scaling groups page.
3. On the Details tab, choose Advanced configurations, **Edit**.

   For **Suspended processes**, choose the process to suspend.
4. Choose **Update**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the **Default** option in **Termination policies** and then stop your instance so that it doesnt pop up a new instamnce when you stop your instance and you can make necessary changes to it